# How to download a file from URL in Linux

Tags: linux, download, wget

Usually one would download a file with a URL ending in the file extension.

To download Ubuntu ISO, one would simple

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.3/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

However, I came accross a site that I suspect uses ASP.Net / IIS.

A link to a ISO is in this form *(I removed link contents incase of ... policies)*:

```
http://some.ip.in.here/website.com/IMAGENAME.ISO?md5=hUhpyFjk7zEskw06ZhrWAQ&expires=1454811899
```

I am not sure how to download this since it has the MD5 and expiry time as parameters, and so wget only downloads a web page, not this ISO.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In such situations I recommend [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) addon for fx

Comment: Are you putting your asp.net url in quotes (")? There is "&" character which will have side effect of running it in background and your server will not get full url.

Comment: @user871199 Could you post this as an answer, this helped me

Comment: Unfortunately, if cookies are involved, it gets a lot harder. If correctly implemented by the web server, it’s even impossible without having a browser open on the same machine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use

```
wget "http://some.ip.in.here/website.com/IMAGENAME.ISO?md5=hUhpyFjk7zEskw06ZhrWAQ&expires=1454811899"
```

**Explanation**: There is "&" character in the URL. On Linux and alike systems, this makes it a background process.

The solution is to enclose url in double quotes (`"`) so that it’s treated as one argument.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just trying to get a reasonable filename the complex URL, you can use the **output-document** option.

```
-O file
--output-document=file
```

Either of these forms will work.

As noted previously, be sure none of the special characters in the URL are getting interpreted by the command parser.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can do this using [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se).

In this first method you would the `-O` flag to write out the file based on the remote name from the URL; in this case it would most likely write the file out to the system as `IMAGENAME.ISO?md5=hUhpyFjk7zEskw06ZhrWAQ&expires=1454811899`; note how the URL value is contained by double quotes since `&` and `?` might be misinterpreted as Bash commands:

```
curl -O -L "http://some.ip.in.here/website.com/IMAGENAME.ISO?md5=hUhpyFjk7zEskw06ZhrWAQ&expires=1454811899";
```

While that method technically “works” but the filename is confusing at best. So in this other method you would use output redirection—with `>` followed by a filename after the URL—to output the file contents to a file named `IMAGENAME.ISO`:

```
curl -L "http://some.ip.in.here/website.com/IMAGENAME.ISO?md5=hUhpyFjk7zEskw06ZhrWAQ&expires=1454811899" > "IMAGENAME.ISO";
```

So if you ask me, the second method works best for most average use. Also notice the `-L` flag being used in both commands; that commands tells Curl to follow any redirection links that a file download URL might have since a lot of times files on download services redirect a few times before landing at the destination payload file.